# How to efficiently convert large numpy array of point cloud data to downsampled 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, point-clouds, downsampling

I have a large numpy array of unordered lidar point cloud data, of shape [num_points, 3], which are the XYZ coordinates of each point. I want to downsample this into a 2D grid of mean height values - to do this I want to split the data into 5x5 X-Y bins and calculate the mean height value (Z coordinate) in each bin.

Does anyone know any quick/efficient way to do this?

Current code:

```
import numpy as np
from open3d import read_point_cloud

resolution = 5

# Code to load point cloud and get points as numpy array
pcloud = read_point_cloud(params.POINT_CLOUD_DIR + "Part001.pcd")
pcloud_np = np.asarray(pcloud.points)

# Code to generate example dataset
pcloud_np = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1000.0, size=(1000,3))

# Current (inefficient) code to quantize into 5x5 XY 'bins' and take mean Z values in each bin
pcloud_np[:, 0:2] = np.round(pcloud_np[:, 0:2]/float(resolution))*float(resolution) # Round XY values to nearest 5

num_x = int(np.max(pcloud_np[:, 0])/resolution)
num_y = int(np.max(pcloud_np[:, 1])/resolution)

mean_height = np.zeros((num_x, num_y))

# Loop over each x-y bin and calculate mean z value 
x_val = 0
for x in range(num_x):
    y_val = 0
    for y in range(num_y):
        height_vals = pcloud_np[(pcloud_np[:,0] == float(x_val)) & (pcloud_np[:,1] == float(y_val))]
        if height_vals.size != 0:
            mean_height[x, y] = np.mean(height_vals)
        y_val += resolution
    x_val += resolution
```

Comment: Could your provide or show the steps to generate an example dataset for us to work with?

Comment: @Jack added code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using an `np.bincount` idiom on the flattened 2d grid. I also took the liberty to add some small fixes to the original code:

```
import numpy as np
#from open3d import read_point_cloud

resolution = 5

# Code to load point cloud and get points as numpy array
#pcloud = read_point_cloud(params.POINT_CLOUD_DIR + "Part001.pcd")
#pcloud_np = np.asarray(pcloud.points)

# Code to generate example dataset
pcloud_np = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1000.0, size=(1000,3))

def f_op(pcloud_np, resolution):
    # Current (inefficient) code to quantize into 5x5 XY 'bins' and take mean Z values in each bin
    pcloud_np[:, 0:2] = np.round(pcloud_np[:, 0:2]/float(resolution))*float(resolution) # Round XY values to nearest 5

    num_x = int(np.max(pcloud_np[:, 0])/resolution) + 1
    num_y = int(np.max(pcloud_np[:, 1])/resolution) + 1

    mean_height = np.zeros((num_x, num_y))

    # Loop over each x-y bin and calculate mean z value 
    x_val = 0
    for x in range(num_x):
        y_val = 0
        for y in range(num_y):
            height_vals = pcloud_np[(pcloud_np[:,0] == float(x_val)) & (pcloud_np[:,1] == float(y_val)), 2]
            if height_vals.size != 0:
                mean_height[x, y] = np.mean(height_vals)
            y_val += resolution
        x_val += resolution

    return mean_height

def f_pp(pcloud_np, resolution):
    xy = pcloud_np.T[:2]
    xy = ((xy + resolution / 2) // resolution).astype(int)
    mn, mx = xy.min(axis=1), xy.max(axis=1)
    sz = mx + 1 - mn
    flatidx = np.ravel_multi_index(xy-mn[:, None], sz)
    histo = np.bincount(flatidx, pcloud_np[:, 2], sz.prod()) / np.maximum(1, np.bincount(flatidx, None, sz.prod()))
    return (histo.reshape(sz), *(xy * resolution))

res_op = f_op(pcloud_np, resolution)
res_pp, x, y = f_pp(pcloud_np, resolution)

from timeit import timeit

t_op = timeit(lambda:f_op(pcloud_np, resolution), number=10)*100
t_pp = timeit(lambda:f_pp(pcloud_np, resolution), number=10)*100

print("results equal:", np.allclose(res_op, res_pp))
print(f"timings (ms) op: {t_op:.3f} pp: {t_pp:.3f}")
```

Sample output:

```
results equal: True
timings (ms) op: 359.162 pp: 0.427
```

Speedup almost 1000x.

Comment: Great thanks works perfectly! I would also like the max height and height variance along with the mean, is this possible with this method?

Comment: @Mark the variance you could in principle compute by the same method using the formula `var(X) = mean(X^2) - mean(X)^2`. This is, however, numerically unstable and not recommended. Instead and since as far as I can see you'll have to do that for the maxima anyway, you could (1) `argsort` the `flatidx` (2) use the resulting index array to reorder the `z` column - this will place all values from a given bin next to each other. (3) determine the bin boundaries (4) use `reduceat` `ufuncs` to compute your desired bin wise quantities, e.g. `np.maximum.reduceat(z_reordered, bin_boundaries)`

Comment: Thanks for this, I have got it working to compute the maximum using your suggested approach. However when I try to do the same for the variance using `np.var.reduceat(z_reordered, bin_boundaries)`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'reduceat'`. Looking at the `ufuncs` documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) suggests that functions such as `mean` and `var` do not support `ufuncs`, is this correct?

Comment: @Mark It would be more accurate to say that they _are_ not ufuncs ;-) Anyway, what you can do is starting from `zr` and `bb`  (short names for z_reordered and bin_boundaries where we assume `bb` to include both `0` and `len(zr)`) (1) compute the bin sizes `bs = np.diff(bb)` (2) calculate the mean `mn = np.add.reduceat(zr, bb[:-1]) / bs` or use the one computed previously (3) subtract the mean from the bins `zc = zr - mn.repeat(bs)` (4) if you want the `unbiased` estimator of the var, adjust the bin sizes by subtracting the degrees of freedom (typically 1)

Comment: @Mark  (5) compute the var: `vr = np.add.reduceat(zc*zc, bb[:-1]) / bs`.